# Angular 6 Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property

Tags: html, angular

In Angular 6 module, I have app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule 
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]   
export class AppModule { }
```

Also, I've footer.component.html
html

```
<footer id="footer" *ngIf="(hrefUrlFor =='creator')">
   <div class="container">
        <ul class="social full_sec">
            <li>Help Center</li>
            <li>Media Center</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</footer>
```

In browser I got errors

> «Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'footer'. »

and

> «Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template.»

Also I've tried with added `CommonModule`, but it still gives error.

Comment: How is the `FooterComponent` component defined? Did you include `CommonModule` in the `imports` of `FooterComponent`?

Comment: can you please share your template file? Please add footer component to the module.ts file. addition to that that please check the property binding in child-parent relation.

Answer (score 5):

Footer component is part of the app module, please check it again. If it's not then you need to import a common module in the parent module of the `footer.component`.

Or try this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FooterComponent } from 'your footer component path';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      CommonModule 
      AppRoutingModule,
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
  ]
})
```

Comment: I have changed my answer please look.

Comment: That was it! If the component is not part of a module then you start getting this weird messages.

Comment: Thanks! Saved the day :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `FooterComponent` in declaration.

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent.
    FooterComponent 
]
```

Comment: Now, it's give following error.
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Comment: Hace you imported CommonModeule?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add in same component also
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
then it will work.
if you only provide in app.module.ts not enough. import in app.component.ts also it will work

Answer (score 0):

remove `(hrefUrlFor` -> `(`

```
<footer id="footer" *ngIf="hrefUrlFor =='creator'">
   <div class="container">
        <ul class="social full_sec">
            <li>Help Center</li>
            <li>Media Center</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution 1: u didn't close parenthesis after creator -----------

```
<footer id="footer" *ngIf="(hrefUrlFor =='creator')">
   <div class="container">
        <ul class="social full_sec">
            <li>Help Center</li>
            <li>Media Center</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</footer>
```

solution 2: try this syntax (remove parenthesis and Apostrophe from creator)

Comment: u forgot a comma after CommonModule, try to fix it. hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like component template  footer.component.html is not rendering anything if condition is false. Add a blank div or span above footer and than it will work.

Comment: please provide a better explaination with code snippets or references.
If there is any assumption then please add and tell it via comment.